# change specified line to uppercase in vim

Tags: vim, uppercase

How to change the specified line to uppercase in vim?
For example,i want to change the lines from 5th till 10th to uppercase.

In `ex` mode ,`5,10gU` or `5,10gUU` can't work.

Comment: You could activate the case-switching operator `~` with the option: `set tildeop`. Then type:  `5G~10G`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the basic idea down with your `ex` command. But `gU` is a *normal* command, not an ex command. You can call a normal command with `norm`, so putting it together, you can do what you want with:

```
:5,10 norm gU$
```

Comment: If you have the "Preserve function" you can keep your cursor with `call Preserve('20,30 norm gU$')`

Basically what it does is to perform a command call without moving your cursor

Here the definition of the function:
https://docwhat.org/vim-preserve-your-cursor-and-window-state/

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient, but the following visual selection method works:

```
5ggV5jU
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter answer:

```
5G5VU
```

Alternate answers:

```
5GgU5j

5GgU10G
```